# Take photo from camera with date like digital camera in iOS

Tags: geolocation, uiimage, xcode4.5, objective-c-2.0, ios6.1

Need to take photo from the application with date and time the photo has been taken to be displayed in photo just like digital camera.

Comment: Do you want the date and time to be part of the image file (i.e. permanent) or just displayed over the top of the image when you view it?

Comment: ya part of image file as permanent

Comment: but text is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1; 
{ 
int w = img.size.width; 

int h = img.size.height; 

//lon = h - lon; 

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage); 

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1); 

char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09"; 

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman); 

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill); 
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1); 

//rotate text 

CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 )); 

CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 4, 52, text, strlen(text)); 

CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 

CGContextRelease(context); 

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); 

return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked]; 
}
```